# Density matrix calculated in two different ways do not match!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Assuming
$|\psi\rangle=|\rightarrow\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\rangle+|\downarrow\rangle)$, then
$\rho_{x+}=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=
\frac{1}{2}[(|\uparrow\rangle+|\downarrow\rangle)(\langle\uparrow|-\langle\downarrow|)]=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\1&1
\end{pmatrix}$.

But then on the other hand we have

$\rho_{z+}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$   and

projection onto $x+$:

$p_{x+}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$    and

$\rho_{x+}=p_{x+}\rho_{z+}p_{x+}^{\dagger}=
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}=
\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$

which is clearly ***not equal*** to the $\rho_{x+}$ we calculated above! Would you please let me know if I am missing a point here?!

Comment: @Dan I don't think so since $p_{x+}=|\rightarrow\rangle\langle\rightarrow|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply missing the fact if the system undergoes projective evolution by the projection operator $P$, then the post-measurement density matrix is given by
$$\rho' = \frac{P\rho P }{\mathrm{Tr}(P\rho P)}$$